# What does one call the circular head of a side street in the shape of a polyp?

Tags: toponyms

I am repeating my question posed in another thread because I can now offer greater clarity in the form of a picture cropped from a Google Earth shot of the actual street location. A second reason for repeating the exercise is that Google Earth revealed that the paved area I need to name actually has the shape of a polyp - or the circular head of a polyp. A third reason is that despite the highly appreciated suggestions, I don't yet have a workable name for the street area in the shape of a polyp head (when photographed from the air, or from a satellite). I would like to write the following sentence: "I walked across the [ ... descriptive and acceptable name for the polyp head ...] to my neighbour across street." Please help! 
[Here is a picture of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbrKw.jpg)

Looking forward very much to possible replies.

Comment: The picture is a little blurry. Are you looking for cul-de-sac: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac

Comment: I hope the coloured markings on the picture help to illuminate the blurry Google Earth picture. Cul-de-sac does not work because this word refers to the whole side street -- not specifically to  the circular paved area. I don't want to write "I walked across the cul-de-sac to my neighbour across the street", it's tautological. I want to name the circular area used as a kind of communal, central area for walking across to neighbours, for kids to hang about on their bikes, for cars to reverse into in order to drive away.

Comment: You can write: I walked across the cul-de-sac to my neighbor's house.  Or: I walked over to my neighbor's on the other side of the cul-de-sac.

Comment: It's not "another thread"; SE is a question-and-answer site. This is the same question as your earlier one, which you could/should have edited. Both sets of answers are relevant to both questions.

Comment: Is the '*cul-de-sac*' a separate side street with a separate name, or is it effectively part of the main street with the same names and numbering?

Comment: -1 for knowingly creating a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a [***cul-de-sac***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac):

> A cul-de-sac (literally "back of the bag" in French) is an expression of French origin also used in Catalan and Occitan referring to a dead end (British English, Canadian, American and Australian English), closed, no through road (British English, Canadian and Australian English) or court (American and Australian English) meaning dead-end street with only one inlet/outlet.

Comment: Better known as Bag End to hobbitses. :)

Answer (score 1):

**I've Got It.**

To my eye, I would refer to the shape as a **loop** or more correctly as a **lollipop**.

A cul-de-sac is simply a no-exit street; the street ends. It's not so much fun as living at/in/around a lollipop. So there. (first post, here)

Now, my question should be, "Does one live at/in/around a lollipop side street?"

My reference is the "Residential Street Pattern Design" found at:
[Research Highlights](http://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/publications/en/rh-pr/tech/socio75.html)

Comment: +1 for the research. But you may wish to check your spelling against the reference you quoted.

Comment: Harmonized spelling with that used in reference given. Thanx.

Comment: My final comments have been removed due to the transgression of duplication. Some comments were left on the duplicate. I think "loop" is the best word I've been given. I suppose one can traverse over a paved loop. "Loop" suggests curvature but also something like a noose. That's exactly what I want.